# How to find first non-zero value in every column of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array of the form:

```
arr=numpy.array([[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]])
```

I want to find the indices of the first index (for every column) where the value is non-zero.

So in this instance, I would like the following to be returned:

```
[0,0,2]
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

#### Indices of first occurrences

Use [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) along that axis (zeroth axis for columns here) on the mask of non-zeros to get the indices of first `matches` (True values) -

```
(arr!=0).argmax(axis=0)
```

Extending to cover generic axis specifier and for cases where no non-zeros are found along that axis for an element, we would have an implementation like so -

```
def first_nonzero(arr, axis, invalid_val=-1):
    mask = arr!=0
    return np.where(mask.any(axis=axis), mask.argmax(axis=axis), invalid_val)
```

Note that since `argmax()` on all `False` values returns `0`, so if the `invalid_val` needed is `0`, we would have the final output directly with `mask.argmax(axis=axis)`.

Sample runs -

```
In [296]: arr    # Different from given sample for variety
Out[296]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

In [297]: first_nonzero(arr, axis=0, invalid_val=-1)
Out[297]: array([ 0,  1, -1])

In [298]: first_nonzero(arr, axis=1, invalid_val=-1)
Out[298]: array([ 0,  0,  1, -1])
```

**Extending to cover all comparison operations**

To find the first `zeros`, simply use `arr==0` as `mask` for use in the function. For first ones equal to a certain value `val`, use `arr == val` and so on for all cases of [`comparisons`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) possible here.

---

#### Indices of last occurrences

To find the last ones matching a certain comparison criteria, we need to flip along that axis and use the same idea of using `argmax` and then compensate for the flipping by offsetting from the axis length, as shown below -

```
def last_nonzero(arr, axis, invalid_val=-1):
    mask = arr!=0
    val = arr.shape[axis] - np.flip(mask, axis=axis).argmax(axis=axis) - 1
    return np.where(mask.any(axis=axis), val, invalid_val)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [320]: arr
Out[320]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

In [321]: last_nonzero(arr, axis=0, invalid_val=-1)
Out[321]: array([ 1,  2, -1])

In [322]: last_nonzero(arr, axis=1, invalid_val=-1)
Out[322]: array([ 0,  1,  1, -1])
```

Again, all cases of [`comparisons`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) possible here are covered by using the corresponding comparator to get `mask` and then using within the listed function.

Comment: Even after all first nonzero values are found, `argmax` still keeps looking unnecessarily through the rest of the array (which might be huge), assuming that larger values might be found there (not knowing that `mask` doesn't have larger values than `1`). Can this be avoided easily, without "manually" implementing slab-wise processing?

Comment: @root I had the same question. Turns out they've [been discussing this since 2012](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2269) and haven't agreed on a simple solution yet!

Comment: That should be "a certain comparison criterion".

Answer (score 7):

The problem, apparently 2D, can be solved by applying to the each row a function that finds the first non-zero element (exactly as in the question).

```py
arr = np.array([[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]])

def first_nonzero_index(array):
    """Return the index of the first non-zero element of array. If all elements are zero, return -1."""
    
    fnzi = -1 # first non-zero index
    indices = np.flatnonzero(array)
       
    if (len(indices) > 0):
        fnzi = indices[0]
        
    return fnzi

np.apply_along_axis(first_nonzero_index, axis=1, arr=arr)

# result
array([ 0,  0,  2, -1])
```

**Explanation**

The [np.flatnonzero(array)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) method (as suggested in the comments by Henrik Koberg) returns "indices that are non-zero in the flattened version of array". The function calculates these indices and returns the first (or -1 if all elements are zero).

The [apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) applys a function to 1-D slices along the given axis. Here since the axis is 1, the function is applied to the rows.

If we can assume that all rows of the input array contain at leas one non-zero element, the solution can be written calculated in one line:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda a: np.flatnonzero(a)[0], axis=1, arr=arr)
```

**Possible variations**

- If we were interested in the last non-zero element, that could be obrained by changing indices[0] into indices[-1] in the function.
- To get the first non-zero by row, we would change axes=1 into axis=0 in np.apply_along_axis

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here is an alternative using `numpy.argwhere` which returns the index of the non zero elements of an array:

```py
array = np.array([0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0])

nonzero_indx = np.argwhere(array).squeeze()
start, end = (nonzero_indx[0], nonzero_indx[-1])
print(array[start], array[end])
```

gives:

```py
1 3
```

Comment: Nice solution! The name `argwhere` is pretty unintuitive.

Comment: I am not sure how this answer applies to the question which concerns a two-dimensional array. Also, here you could just use `flatnonzero(array)` instead of `argwhere(array).squeeze()`

Comment: Thanks Henrik,
I did non know the flatnonzero() method, I will complete this answer with it.

Concerning the dimensionality of the problem: The array is indeed 2D but the asked problem is 1D: "find the first non-zero element in each row". This means the 1D solution could be applied to each row and to obtain the 2D solution

Comment: Agreed, Marco. Just one last remark: While this solution works well for smaller arrays, it will perform poorly for larger ones. This is because `apply_along_axis` is a non-vectorized convenience function. In this case, I would rather go with the accepted answer.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you on this

Comment: This runs a for loop and is not vectorized.