# Find index of first element with condition in numpy array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I'm trying find the index of the first element bigger than a threshold, like this:

```
index = 0
while timeStamps[index] < self.stopCount and index < len(timeStamps):
    index += 1
```

Can this be done in a one-liner? I found:

```
index = next((x for x in timeStamps if x <= self.stopCount), 0)
```

I'm not sure what this expression does and it seems to return 0 always... Could somebody point out the error and explain the expression?

Comment: Why is it important to write it in a one-liner? One liners produce the same machine code and are more difficult to understand and debug

Comment: Good point. I found it rather slow, but perhaps there is no faster way. It is merely for comparison.

Comment: More importantly, why are you using loops with numpy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to use [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) (see [this post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269413/11946287)). So your code would become something like

```
(timeStamps > self.stopCount).argmax()
```

the caveat is that if the condition is never satisfied the `argmax` will return 0.

Comment: That is exactly what I want, including caveat.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```py
import numpy as np

threshold = 20

sample_array = np.array([10,11,12,13,21,200,1,2])

idx = np.array([np.where(sample_array > threshold)]).min()
print(idx)
#4
```

Comment: Wrapping in an extra list and an array seem like total overkill here

Answer (score 0):

this one liner will work

```py
sample_array = np.array([10,11,12,13,21,200,1,2])

# oneliner
print(sum(np.cumsum(arr>threshold)==0))
```

`np.cumsum(sample_array>threshold)==0)` will have value 0 until element is bigger than threshold

Comment: This is such a convoluted way, but it sure does work.