# Manim: run_time of animation is not as expected

Tags: python, animation, manim

I want `manim` to spend 4 seconds animating the creation of a sector. Although the whole animation lasts 4 seconds, the creation portion is only half that. I've tried extending the `run_time` parameter but to get the full 4 seconds for creation I have to make the duration 8 seconds. The actual drawing is finished at 4 seconds but then I have an animation 50% longer than necessary with the second half just sitting there doing nothing. I must be doing something wrong but I'm very new to manim so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Maybe it's the `rate_func` parameter.

MWE:

```py
from manimlib.imports import *

class Circ(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        shape = Sector(color=GOLD_B,
                       fill_color=GOLD_B,
                       fill_opacity=1,
                       angle=360*DEGREES)
        self.play(ShowCreation(shape,
                               lag_ratio=0,
                               rate_func=lambda t: linear(1 - t),
                               run_time=4*2)) # because we want 4 seconds for the circle's creation
```

I have tried it without the `lag_ratio` (not actually sure yet what that does). I borrowed the `rate_func` from `Uncreate` in `animation.py`. My current best guess is that this function is taking the full time of the `run_time` parameter but only looks like its using half. I have tried other functions, the original `Uncreate` is `smooth`. It is different but still doesn't appear to fill the full 4 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following, if we print the control points of the curve we see the following:

```py
print(shape.points)
```

Returns:

```
[[ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 3.33333333e-01 -8.16431199e-17  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 6.66666667e-01 -1.63286240e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -2.44929360e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -2.44929360e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -2.61799388e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 8.92226904e-01 -5.21986659e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 7.07106781e-01 -7.07106781e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 7.07106781e-01 -7.07106781e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 5.21986659e-01 -8.92226904e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 2.61799388e-01 -1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [-1.83697020e-16 -1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [-1.83697020e-16 -1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [-2.61799388e-01 -1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [-5.21986659e-01 -8.92226904e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-7.07106781e-01 -7.07106781e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-7.07106781e-01 -7.07106781e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-8.92226904e-01 -5.21986659e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-1.00000000e+00 -2.61799388e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-1.00000000e+00  1.22464680e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [-1.00000000e+00  1.22464680e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [-1.00000000e+00  2.61799388e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-8.92226904e-01  5.21986659e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-7.07106781e-01  7.07106781e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-7.07106781e-01  7.07106781e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-5.21986659e-01  8.92226904e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-2.61799388e-01  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 6.12323400e-17  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 6.12323400e-17  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 2.61799388e-01  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 5.21986659e-01  8.92226904e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 7.07106781e-01  7.07106781e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 7.07106781e-01  7.07106781e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 8.92226904e-01  5.21986659e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  2.61799388e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 6.66666667e-01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 3.33333333e-01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]
```

We can see that many of the first control points are zero vectors, we would have to analyze the Sector source code to solve this problem, I suggest do something like:

```py
class Circ(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        shape = Sector(
                       color=GOLD_B,
                       fill_color=GOLD_B,
                       fill_opacity=1,
                       stroke_width=4,
                       stroke_color=TEAL,
                       angle=360*DEGREES
        )
        shape.points = shape.points[32:-1] # <- because there are 33 zero vectors at the beginning and 1 at the end
        self.play(
            ShowCreation(
                shape,
                run_time=4,
                rate_func=lambda t: linear(1-t)
            )
        )
        self.wait()
```

Obviously, the amount of zeros can change depending on the `Sector` mobject that we use, so you will have to find a way to filter those zero vectors at the beginning that are not necessary, perhaps this can be easily corrected in the definition of the Sector class.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I used `shape.points = shape.points[(shape.points!=0).argmax(axis=0)[0]-1:-1]` to filter the beginning. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269390/numpy-how-to-find-first-non-zero-value-in-every-column-of-a-numpy-array

Comment: Yesterday I started watching your video series on manim. Thank you for making it and for answering my question here so promptly.