# How to count number of False values that precede at least one True with Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking to count the number of `False` values that precede at least one `True` value for each row in a 2D Numpy array.

For example the desired function would act as below:

```py
>>> x = np.array([[0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1]], dtype='bool')
>>> x
array([[False, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
>>> foo(x)
3
```

The result is 3 since the first row has two `False` before a `True` value, with the final False ignored. There's one `False` that precedes `True` on the second row and none on the third.

Rows with no `True` value (all False) count as `0`.

Is there a vectorised means of calculating this without iterating through the rows? Currently the only ways I have would be counting transitions with `numpy.diff()` or iterating through each row individually.

Comment: what would be the result for a line like [F,T,F,T,F,F,F,T]... 5?

Comment: @some_name.py Yes 5 would be the result for a line like that. It's a count where all Falses after the last True are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a oneliner:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1]], dtype='bool')
np.max((~x).cumsum(axis = 1) * x, axis = 1 )

# array([2, 1, 0])
```

To show the calculation:

```
not_x = ~x    # Reverse the Trues and Falses
temp = not_x.cumsum( axis = 1 )  # cumsum the Falses by row.
temp

# array([[1, 2, 2, 3],
#        [0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0]])

temp *= x    # Zero the result only where x is False
temp 
# array([[0, 0, 2, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0]])     

temp.max( axis = 1 )  # Find the max in each row.
# array([2, 1, 0])
```

Comment: This is very nice, thank you! About 3 times faster than what I had worked out below.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1]], dtype='bool')
# reverse x:
idx = np.arange(x.shape[1]-1, -1, -1)
x_reverse = x[:, idx]
# find the number of Falses that come after the last true
x_int = x_reverse.astype(int)
x_sparse = (x_int==np.cumsum(x_int, axis = 1))*x_int
rows, falses_after = np.where(x_sparse,)
# find the total number of Falses
falses_sum = (1-x).sum(1)
#subtract the number of falses that come after the last true from the total number of falses
falses_before = falses_sum-falses_after
```

Output:

```
falses_before = [2 1 0]
```

**Edit:** I didn't realize you were looking for the sum of Falses that come before Trues. you can get this number by doing `falses_before.sum()`

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Comment: Realised an issue with this on testing, empty rows have values added. E.g., `array([[False, False, False], [False,  True, False],[False, False, False]])` should return only 1, but returns 5 instead due to the empty rows. 
Partly my fault for not clarifying empty row behaviour! Rows of all False should sum to 0 as they do not precede a True value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet. `np.where(i == True)` is looking for index of item in array, and then we use `j[0]+1` to get our first occurrence and add 1, because arrays are numbered from 0

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1]], dtype='bool')

for i in x:
    j, = np.where(i == True)
    print(j[0]+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by finding the last item on each row, and using the indexes to create a mask. The mask is then used to count the instances of False.

The `last_nonzero` function is taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269413/14354978).

```py
def last_nonzero(arr: np.ndarray, axis=0, invalid_val=-1):
    """
    Attribution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269413/14354978
    """
    mask = arr != False
    val = arr.shape[axis] - np.flip(mask, axis=axis).argmax(axis=axis) - 1
    return np.where(mask.any(axis=axis), val, invalid_val)

def count_false_pre_true(arr: np.ndarray):
    mask = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype='bool')
    up_to = last_nonzero(arr, axis=1, invalid_val=0)
    for i, m in enumerate(up_to):
        mask[i, :m] = True
    return (arr[mask] == False).sum()
```

The enumerate loop to edit the mask is the only part that needs to be vectorised, but I can't figure out how to do that, any comments would be appreciated!

This works only with 2D numpy arrays, so 1D arrays need to be wrapped again.